# How can I call a Haskell function from Golang?

Tags: haskell, go, ffi

I am a python developer making the shift to Golang, so I'm sorry for the noob question. I am responsible for taking some Haskell code, for which we have python bindings, and making it callable from Go. I have a shared object file, `_foo.so`, that I want to somehow import into Go and call a la:

```golang
import (
    f "_foo.so"
)

func DoBar() {
    return f.Bar()
}
```

Is this possible? I don't even have the first idea of where to begin, but I'm hoping that pseudo code gets the idea across.

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

Comment: You will have to go through C, their common denominator. There are tutorials for calling Haskell from C, and calling C from Go.

Comment: I know it isn't always an option, but if you can avoid sharing an address space and instead use IPC in some way then you'll save yourself some pain.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need to go through C.

Good news: the python binding you have goes through C already. It means that haskell code exposes all the necessary API as C functions, you just need to find out how the API looks like and call it using `cgo`. You probably don't need to know anything about haskell.

Assuming you have access to the source code, you should look for `*.c` and `*.h` files (often located in a `cbits` folder). If you don't know C, then ask your teammates to help.

If you don't have access to the code, then you may try to guess the C API using the python binding. Though it'll be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by this question, so I implemented it.

See this repo: https://github.com/rusq/gohaskell/

Go program calls `fibonacci` Haskell function.